# what happens to a integrated function when $f(x)$ passes through origin?

Tags: integration, derivatives

> Let $y=f(x)$ be a curve such that the slope of it's gradient is given by $x^2-3$, find the function $f(x)$ if it passes through the origin.

since $f'(x) = x^2 -3$, integrating it to find $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} - 3x +C$

I understand that "Passes through origin" basically means the function passes through $[0,0]$ but the answer is just $\frac{x^3}{3} - 3x$

I do not understand why does $C$ goes to $0$? How do I visualise it graphically?

Comment: $C=0$ is a consequences of $f(0)=0$, which is the condition imposed by requiring it to pass through the origin. It's the initial condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While taking the derivative of something is unique - i.e. there is only one possible outcome, there are infinitely many functions that are the integral of something. For example, the functions $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x+1$ are different, but their derivatives are both 1. The reason behind that is the derivative represents the *gradient* of a curve, and $x$ and $x+1$ are only different by shifting upwards by 1 - they actually have the same gradient - in general any line of the form $y=mx+b$ has gradient $m$ regardless of the value of $b$, we can extend this idea to more complicated functions, by noticing that moving things up and down doesn't actually change how steep they are.

Effectively, you can have a whole bunch of $f(x)$ that have derivative $f'(x)=x^2-3$, since we can shift functions up and down and they keep the same slope - for example the function $f(x)=\frac13x^3-3x$ has that as its derivative, but so does $g(x)=\frac13x^3-3x+1$, which goes through the point $(0,1)$ instead of $(0,0)$. This is because when you derive a function of the form of *something* plus $C$, the constant $C$ is effectively lost (since its derivative is zero), and so you lose a bit of information when you derive functions.

Then, when we integrate (and "undo" the derivative), we actually don't have all the information we started with, and can only get part of the solution, but it could be plus any constant $C$, and so we need to know *a point* so that we can work out how far up or down the function actually is. I'd really encourage you to play around with something like Desmos, and see how applying a vertical translation doesn't actually change our slope, and so doesn't change the derivative.

I'll also quickly outline the method to find this $C$ value in general, in case you aren't fully comfortable with it. Feel free to ask me to elaborate on anything :):

Essentially, we integrate $f'(x)$ to get $f(x)$, which has some $C$ we don't know added to it. As such, we substitute a specific $x$ value in (of the point we know, in this case $x=0$, because we know that at $x=0$, $f(x)=0$. Then we just rearrange to make $C$ the subject:
\begin{align}
f(x) & = \frac13x^3 - 3x + C \\
0 = f(0) & = \frac13\times0^3 - 3\times0 + C \\
0 & = C 
\end{align}
and then we put this $C$ back in, to get $f(x)=\frac13x^3-3x$. This method works for any function, and any point to substitute.

I should also note that just because $f(x)$ goes through the origin, that doesn't mean $C=0$ - for example if we have $f'(x)=-\sin(x)$, the integral of this is $f(x)=\cos(x) + C$ - and if that passes through the origin then we actually get $C=-1$, so the $C=0$ in your example is just a special case because of your function.